# Jquery wizard menu validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/webform_to_wizard/# Please visit this link in this jquery wizard there is no validation kept for each step when we click next. I need a code where it should validate those field before proceeding to next step.I don't know Jquery much since am a beginner it will be very helpful if someone helps me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, why not use the jQuery Validation Plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

A tutorial is here:
http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-validation.php

It's very easy to implmeent, just include it and run some code on document.ready where you state which fields need what validation...